# IF EXISTS-error

Tags: t-sql

Could someone tell me the right use of `IF EXISTS`. I have this query, but I have problem with `IF EXISTS` function.

```
insert into master.dbo.turnover3(shop,somefield)
select '301',Curr_Turnover 
from [S301].vpm.dbo.BO_POS_SAP_Turnover
where datediff(day,left(Sale_Date,16),getdate())= '0' if not exists (select NULL)
```

Comment: That syntax is not correct. Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

The right use of `if exists` is easy.  It is not valid syntax for a `select`, `update`, or `SQL` statement.  Your query would work fine without it:

```
insert into master.dbo.turnover3(shop,somefield)
    select '301',Curr_Turnover 
    from [S301].vpm.dbo.BO_POS_SAP_Turnover
    where datediff(day,left(Sale_Date,16),getdate())= '0' ;
```

`if exists` *is* part of T-SQL.  That is, you can write scripts with it.  With this syntax, it is just another variation on the `if` statement:

```
if not exists (select *
               from master.dbo.turnover3(shop,somefield)
               where shop = '301'
              )
begin
    insert into master.dbo.turnover3(shop,somefield)
        select '301',Curr_Turnover 
        from [S301].vpm.dbo.BO_POS_SAP_Turnover
        where datediff(day,left(Sale_Date,16),getdate())= '0' ;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not doing an update here (or since there is no else part), you don't need to check for the existence of records. **`No records found means no records inserted`**.

```
insert into master.dbo.turnover3(shop,somefield)
select '301',Curr_Turnover 
from [S301].vpm.dbo.BO_POS_SAP_Turnover
where datediff(day,left(Sale_Date,16),getdate()) = 0
```

Also as a side note, not sure what you do with `left(Sale_Date,16)` in the *`datediff`* function in the *`where`* clause. If `Scale_Date` is a `date/datetime` type you could use it as `datediff(day,Sale_Date,getdate()= 0`